# VB.NET - How to find all modes (most frequent occurring numbers) in an array

Tags: vb.net

So a Mode is the most frequent number in a dataset.

I've already managed to solve it, but it can only get 1 mode.
Here's my code:

```
Dim mode = inputX.GroupBy(Function(n) n).Select(Function(g) New With {.Number = g.Key, .Quantity = g.Count}).OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Quantity).FirstOrDefault
If mode.Quantity > 1 Then
  result = mode.Number.ToString() + "    Quantity: " + mode.Quantity.ToString()
Else
  result = "None."
End If
```

Now even though I inputted `29 29 35 30 30`, which has 2 modes, it only shows `29`, which is the first mode that it got. I want to get two modes or more.

I've been racking my brains and kept searching for answers, but I couldn't make it work.

I just started learning this language 2 days ago.

Comment: Remove `.FirstOrDefault()` -- *Mode* is a term you made up. Try to rephrase that.

Comment: Didn't work. Also _Mode_ is an actual mathematical term, but sure I'll rephrase it.

Comment: Probably because you need a loop to inspect all the objects that have `.Quantity > 1` -- Mode is the most frequent number in a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting myself from a comment in [LINQ: Mean, Median, and Mode](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/linq-mean-median-and-mode/):

```
Dim inputX = {29, 29, 35, 30, 30}

Dim modes = From a In
                (From n In inputX
                 Group n By n Into g = Count()
                 Select g, n)
            Where a.g =
            (From n In inputX
             Group n By n Into g = Count() Select g).Max
            Select a.n

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", modes))
```

Outputs:

```
29, 30
```